# bootstrap nested row issue not in one row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i want picture and L1 and L2 be in one row ...
but L2 always in botton of picture ...
why ?
i think my nested row is correct ... is that OK ?
[image: L2 not be in pic Row]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>appLanding</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img src="face-03.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" style="margin-top: 4%">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">L1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">L2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" dir="rtl">
            <div style="height:120px;width:100%;overflow:auto;padding: 1%">
                As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we
                call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to be using more of the [Bootstrap Media Alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/gxLtnLp0/1/) to review the code you provided, but modified using the Bootstrap Media Alignment.

Notice the img-responsive class has been removed. If added it floats the rows to the left.

Let me know if that helps.

```css
.top {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#no-inline-styles {
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- EXAMPLE CODE STARTS -->

<div class="container top">
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
      <img class="media-object img-rounded" src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>L1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>L2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="no-inline-styles">
                As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we
                call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.
            </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<!-- EXAMPLE CODE ENDS -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```